# SetUp, initialize Junit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am trying to test my 3 classes that sorts string arrays in different ways!

I know that there is a method that initialize an array and then uses them in every single of my tests.

So far this is my code:

```
public class SortingTest {

    public insertionSort is = new insertionSort();
    public bubbleSort bs = new bubbleSort();
    @Test
    public void testBubbleSort() {
        String [] sortedArray ={"Chesstitans", "Ludo", "Monkey", "Palle"};
        bs.sort(sortedArray);
        assertArrayEquals(sortedArray, x);
    }
    @Test
    public void testInsertionSort() {


    }
    @Test
    public void testMergeSort() {


    }
    @Test
    public void testSelectionSort() {


    }
    @Before
    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        String[]x ={"Ludo", "Chesstitans", "Palle", "Monkey"};
    }
}
```

Eventhough I have tried both setUp and initialize method it doesn't seem to find x what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make `x` a member variable of the class `SortingTest`

```
public class SortingTest {  

    private String[] x; 

    @Before
    public void init() {
      x = new String {"Ludo", "Chesstitans", "Palle", "Monkey"};
    }
}
```

Comment: so i need to initilize it as a public variable? doesnt that ruin the whole point of method initilize?

Comment: if i do it like that and it sorts the x array first time. Wont all my other tests be useless because the array is already sorted?

Comment: 1 fix to your code but else it was perfect! :D

x = new String[]{"Ludo","Chesstitans","Palle", "Monkey"};

Answer (score 2):

`setUp` should initialize some *field* member so other methods have access to it. If you initialize a local variable it will be lost when you exit setUp variable.

In this case the good thing would have two members:

- originalArray
- sortedArray

In each test method you could sort the originalArray and compare the result against your already sortedArray.

Comment: Exactly this is what i want but do i have to do it in each individual sorting method? isnt there a way for it to initilize it every time it uses a new method?

Comment: If I don't remember bad, it's that way. setUp is called before each method execution (even I'm not sure if the test object is created again with each test method). So initialize them in setUp and use them freely.

Comment: In fact @munyengm is right, you could assign the values directly on member declaration without the need of a setUp method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `x` a member of a class, so that it's visible in all methods.